# Check if property exists in Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, uncaught-reference-error

```js
class User{
        constructor(username,description){
            this.username = username
            this.description = description
        }
        printInfo(info){
            if (info in this){
                return info
            }
        }
    }
    
    let newUser = new User("testUsername","testDescription")
    
    newUser.printInfo(username)
```

When I try this, it gives me an error on line 17 about `Uncaught ReferenceError`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the quotes when passing the *username* property name. The passed `username` argument has to be a **string** `newUser.printInfo("username")`.

Without the quotes, it will try to reference a (non-existing) global variable named `username`.

Note that your `printInfo` function will just return the name of the property (same as the parameter), not the actual value. If you want to return the username value you have to access that key as `this[info]`:

```
    ...
    printInfo(info){
        if (info in this){
            return this[info];
        }
    }
```